# can't get nativescript-plugin-firebase demo app to work

Tags: firebase, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to get the nativescript-plugin-firebase demo app of Eddy Verbruggen to work but i keep getting errors, please help

this is a link to the demo:
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo#nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo-app

i have the newest Google Play Services and Google Repository installed and done all the things that were told in the tutorial but still no succes

```
D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\weernietgoed>cd D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase
```

D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase>tns run android
Executing before-prepare hook from D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\hooks\before-prepare\nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Found peer TypeScript 1.8.10
Project successfully prepared (android)
WARNING: The file: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\node_modules\nativescript-plugin-firebase\platforms\android\README.md is depricated, you can read more about what will be the expected plugin structure here: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/migrating-n-android-plugins-from-version-1.7-to-2.0

:config phase:  createDefaultIncludeFiles
        +found plugins: nativescript-plugin-firebase
        +found plugins: tns-core-modules-widgets

:config phase:  createPluginsConfigFile
         Creating product flavors include.gradle file in D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android/configurations folder...

:config phase:  pluginExtend
        +applying configuration from: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\configurations\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\configurations\nativescript-plugin-firebase\include.gradle
        +applying configuration from: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\configurations\tns-core-modules-widgets\include.gradle

:config phase:  copyAarDependencies

:config phase:  addAarDependencies
        +adding dependency: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\libs\aar\firebase-release.aar
        +adding dependency: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\libs\aar\widgets-release.aar
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preF0F1DebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkF0F1DebugManifest
:preF0F1ReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2421Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCore940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon940Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareFirebaseReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareFirebasedemoRuntimeUnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareWidgetsReleaseLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:prepareF0F1DebugDependencies
:compileF0F1DebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0F1DebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:cleanLocalAarFiles
:ensureMetadataOutDir
:collectAllJars
:setProperties
:asbg:generateInterfaceNamesList
:asbg:runAstParser UP-TO-DATE
:asbg:generateBindings UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:compileF0F1DebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeF0F1DebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateF0F1DebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:processF0F1DebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\google-services.json
:generateF0F1DebugResources
:mergeF0F1DebugResources
D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png: Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
:mergeF0F1DebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':mergeF0F1DebugResources'.

  > D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png: Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 20.794 secs
Command D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\gradlew.bat failed with exit code 1

## run android

┌────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ Usage                  │ Synopsis                                                                                │
│ Run on all connected   │ $ tns run android [--key-store-path  --key-store-password  --key   │
│ devices and running    │ -store-alias  --key-store-alias-password ] [--release] [--justlaunch]   │
│ emulators              │                                                                                         │
│ Run on a selected      │ $ tns run android --device  [--key-store-path  --key-store        │
│ connected device or    │ -password  --key-store-alias  --key-store-alias-password ] [- │
│ running emulator       │ -release] [--justlaunch]                                                                │
│ Start an emulator and  │ $ tns run android --emulator [] [--key-store-path  --key   │
│ run the app inside it  │ -store-password  --key-store-alias  --key-store-alias-password          │
│                        │ ] [--release] [--justlaunch]                                                  │
└────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

Runs your project on a connected Android device or in a native Android emulator, if configured. This is shorthand for prepare, build and deploy. While your app is running, prints the output from the application in the console.

#### Options

```
* --watch - If set, when you save changes to the project, changes are automatically synchronized to the connected device.
* --device - Specifies a connected device on which to run the app.
* --emulator - If set, runs the app in a native emulator for the target platform, if configured. When set, you can also set any other valid combination of emulator options as listed by $ tns help emulate android.
* --release - If set, produces a release build. Otherwise, produces a debug build. When set, you must also specify the --key-store-* options.
* --key-store-path - Specifies the file path to the keystore file (P12) which you want to use to code sign your APK. You can use the --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.
* --key-store-password - Provides the password for the keystore file specified with --key-store-path. You can use the --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.
* --key-store-alias - Provides the alias for the keystore file specified with --key-store-path. You can use the --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.    * --key-store-alias-password - Provides the password for the alias specified with --key-store-alias-password. You can use the --key-store-* options along with --release to produce a signed release build. You need to specify all --key-store-* options.
* --justlaunch - If set, does not print the application output in the console.
```

#### Attributes

```
* <Device ID> is the index or name of the target device as listed by $ tns device android
* <Emulator Options> is any valid combination of options as listed by $ tns help emulate android
```

Sending exception report (press Ctrl+C to stop).....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the actual issue and did you try to solve it already?

I mean, this file has a path of 247 characters where only 240 are allowed:

Error: File path too long on Windows, keep below 240 characters : D:\s_a_m\nativescript\firstProject\nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo\Firebase\platforms\android\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\9.4.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png

So I guess move the project up a folder and clone the demo app in a folder with a short(er) name.

Comment: thank you, I saw it but didn't know how it would be possible that there were so many characters since I just used: git clone https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase-demo and did not give it a different name. Glad that i can go on with your plugin!